# Interaction of charges and EM wave striking the surface of a conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations

Microscopically, what exactly happens between the charges on the surface of a conductor and the $E$ and $H$ components of the obliquely incident EM wave (in a classic viewpoint of field theory)?

We all know about boundary condition equations and I'm not looking for any answer which is based on those equations. My question is about the physics behind what results in those equations. My question is about what happens to the charges on the surface and how the wave affect them and how they react to reproduce the reflected wave.

In this scenario, is the surface current the result of both tangential $E_t$ and $H_t$ or it's just the result of tangential $E_t$ component of the wave? If $Ht$ contributes to the surface current, what is the mechanism and how it happens?

What happens to normal components of the incident wave on the surface? How do they interact with charge carriers on the surface?

How do the charges behave on the surface to reproduce the normal components of the reflected wave?

(Again I just want to know a physical description of what happens there on the surface which results in the reflected wave, in a classical viewpoint. Boundary conditions are the results of that interaction not the reason for that.)

Comment: how is this different than the [photoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect) or is that the technical term for what youre talking about?

Comment: @vzn maybe they have similar basics, but no my question is not about the photoelectric effect and I don't discuss the frequency of the EM wave. My question particularly applies to a general situation that EM wave impinges on the surface of a conductor and reflects back . It is about how the charges on the surface respond to the components of the incident wave to produce the reflected wave through EM waves radiation mechanism; not necessarily about emission or escape of the electrons from the surface.